# Creating 2 charts show 2 different data in one graph (asp.net MVC)

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net-mvc, charts

Hello I know it might sound confusing but I hope I can get help ....

Well I'm working on asp.net mvc using MYSQL for database , 
and what I'm trying to make is a 2 charts show 2 different data in one graph something like this [image]
so in my controller I tried to return both but it shows one chart only ...

The controller :

```
    public class BartestController : Controller
    {
        public static List<string> getChartData()
        {
            var returnData = new List<string>();
            var Con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYdb"].ConnectionString);

            //BarChart1
            var MySql = new MySqlCommand("select sum(c.eff) as efficinciey , d.className from usecases c , classes d where d.ClassID = c.ClassID And  c.stID=3  group by ClassName;", Con);
            var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySql);
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);

            var chartLabel = new StringBuilder();
            var chartData = new StringBuilder();
            chartLabel.Append("[");
            chartData.Append("[");

            foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                chartLabel.Append(string.Format("'{0}',", row["ClassName"].ToString()));
                chartData.Append(string.Format("{0},", row["eff"].ToString()));
            }


            chartData.Length++;
            chartData.Append("]");
            chartLabel.Length++;
            chartLabel.Append("]");
            chartData = chartData.Remove(chartData.Length - 3, 2);
            chartLabel = chartLabel.Replace("'", "g");
            chartLabel = chartLabel.Remove(chartLabel.Length - 3, 2);
            returnData.Add(chartLabel.ToString());
            returnData.Add(chartData.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("returnData: " + chartLabel);
            return returnData;
        }

        public static List<string> getChartData2()
        {
            var returnData1 = new List<string>();
            var Con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYdb"].ConnectionString);

            //BarChart1
            var MySql1 = new MySqlCommand(" select count(c.UseCaseID) , d.ClassName from usecases c , classes d where d.ClassID= c.ClassID group by d.ClassName;", Con);
            var dataAdapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySql1);
            var dataset1 = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter1.Fill(dataset1);

            var chartLabel1 = new StringBuilder();
            var chartData1 = new StringBuilder();
            chartLabel1.Append("[");
            chartData1.Append("[");

            foreach (DataRow row in dataset1.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                chartLabel1.Append(string.Format("'{0}',", row["ClassName"].ToString()));
                chartData1.Append(string.Format("{0},", row["count(c.UseCaseID)"].ToString()));
            }

            chartData1.Length++;
            chartData1.Append("]");
            chartLabel1.Length++;
            chartLabel1.Append("]");
            chartData1 = chartData1.Remove(chartData1.Length - 3, 2);
            chartLabel1 = chartLabel1.Replace("'", "g");
            chartLabel1 = chartLabel1.Remove(chartLabel1.Length - 3, 2);
            returnData1.Add(chartLabel1.ToString());
            returnData1.Add(chartData1.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("returnData: " + chartLabel1);
            return returnData1;    
        }

        public ActionResult BartestChart()
        {
            List<string> returnData = getChartData();
            ViewData["Chart"] = returnData;
            List<string> returnData1 = getChartData2();
            ViewData["Chart"] = returnData1;
            return View(getChartData());
            return View(getChartData2());
        }
    }
}
```

The view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BartestChart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    int x = 0;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<body style="height: 331px">
    <div style="padding-top:50px"></div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="Chart" width="500" height="500" style="border:dashed;border-color:lightgray"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        var chartLabel;
        var chartData = [];
    </script>

    @foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.Chart)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            <script>
                        chartData = @label;
                        console.log(chartData);
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                        chartLabel = "@label";
                        chartLabel = chartLabel.replace(/g/g, "\"");
                        chartLabel = JSON.parse(chartLabel);
                        console.log(chartLabel);
            </script>
        }
        x++;

    }
    <script>
        var chartLabel1;
        var chartData1 = [];
    </script>

    @foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.Chart)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            <script>
                        chartData1 = @label;
                        console.log(chartData1);
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                        chartLabel1 = "@label";
                        chartLabel1 = chartLabel1.replace(/g/g, "\"");
                        chartLabel1 = JSON.parse(chartLabel1);
                        console.log(chartLabel1);
            </script>
        }
        x++;

    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');

                        var barData = {
                            labels: chartLabel,
                            datasets: [
                                        {
                                            label: 'Efficiency',
                                            fillColor: "cadetblue",
                                            strokeColor: "cadetblue",
                                            data: chartData

                                        } ],
                            labels: chartLabel1,
                            datasets: [
                                        {
                                            label: 'Efficiency',
                                            fillColor: "green",
                                            strokeColor: "green",
                                            data: chartData1

                                        } ]


                        };

                        var skillsChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barData);    

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The chart works fine before I added new command and everything to show the sec chart.... I hope I can get help

Comment: how does this work when you use these lines after each other: return View(getChartData()); return View(getChartData2());. Once the first is executed, then there is no effect for the second return, the method exists.

Comment: moreover, you are using ViewData["Chart"] for the first chart data and for the second chart data, this is totally wrong. For each data you need to use a seperate ViewBag element. For example: ViewData["ChartOne"] = returnData; ViewData["ChartTow"] = returnData1;

Comment: @alaa_sayegh Yes it's work only by executing one only so i want to know how to execute both or show 2 different data ...

Comment: @alaa_sayegh .so do u think i should use one return value (return View(getChartData()); ) with diffrent ViewData ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Place the data for the 2 charts in different ViewBag elements:

```
public ActionResult BartestChart()
{
   List<string> returnData = getChartData();
   ViewBag.ChartOne = returnData;
   List<string> returnData1 = getChartData2();
   ViewBag.ChartTwo = returnData1;
   return View();
}
```

And in your View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BartestChart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    int x = 0;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body style="height: 331px">
    <div style="padding-top:50px"></div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="Chart" width="500" height="500" style="border:dashed;border-color:lightgray"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        var chartLabel;
        var chartData = [];
    </script>

    @foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.ChartOne)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            <script>
                        chartData = @label;
                        console.log(chartData);
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                        chartLabel = "@label";
                        chartLabel = chartLabel.replace(/g/g, "\"");
                        chartLabel = JSON.parse(chartLabel);
                        console.log(chartLabel);
            </script>
        }
        x++;

    }
    <script>
        var chartLabel1;
        var chartData1 = [];
    </script>


@foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.ChartTwo)
{
    <script>
                    chartData1 = @label;
                    console.log(chartData1);
    </script>

}
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');

                var barData = {
                    labels: chartLabel,
                    datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Efficiency',
                                    fillColor: "IndianRed",
                                    strokeColor: "IndianRed",
                                    data: chartData1

                                } ,

                                {
                                    label: 'Efficiency',
                                    fillColor: "Black",
                                    strokeColor: "Black",
                                    data: chartData

                                } ]
    };

                var skillsChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barData);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why it didn't work? give more details, any error? This will create two charts, one with returnData and one with returnData1. Or you want the two datasets in one chart? If yes, then i will update my answer

Comment: there is no error but the thing is that it's only create one chart , and yes i want the two datasets in one chart :D

Comment: but if you need them on the same chart, then you must use the same labels (y-axis) for both. Are you getting data already displayed now? can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: ya for the label thing I'm using the Same label ok , ill take screenshot

Comment: try the code which i pasted now. the method BartestChart and the view code. you need to use two different viewbags. if it still doesn't work, paste please your corrected code with the screenshot to take a look at it!

Comment: paste your code please in the answer where you pasted your screenshot!!

Comment: you need to check the data in returndata and returndata1. I think your data is wrong. It is not matching the same label content

Comment: the data is not wrong ..... its show that there is  data. i think the problem is in the view with displaying the sec data ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Third-Party charts Like Google charts or AM Charts [Link For AM Charts Website](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/exporting-chart-to-image/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is the screenshot]

The view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BartestChart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    int x = 0;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body style="height: 331px">
    <div style="padding-top:50px"></div>
    <div>
        <canvas id="Chart" width="500" height="500" style="border:dashed;border-color:lightgray"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        var chartLabel;
        var chartData = [];
    </script>

    @foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.ChartOne)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            <script>
                        chartData = @label;
                        console.log(chartData);
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                        chartLabel = "@label";
                        chartLabel = chartLabel.replace(/g/g, "\"");
                        chartLabel = JSON.parse(chartLabel);
                        console.log(chartLabel);
            </script>
        }
        x++;

    }
    <script>
        var chartLabel1;
        var chartData1 = [];
    </script>

    @foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.ChartTwo)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            <script>
                        chartData1 = @label;
                        console.log(chartData1);
            </script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script>
                        chartLabel1 = "@label";
                        chartLabel1 = chartLabel1.replace(/g/g, "\"");
                        chartLabel1 = JSON.parse(chartLabel1);
                        console.log(chartLabel1);
            </script>
        }
        x++;

    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');

                    var barData = {
                        labels: chartLabel,
                        datasets: [
                                    {
                                        label: 'Efficiency',
                                        fillColor: "cadetblue",
                                        strokeColor: "cadetblue",
                                        data: chartData

                                    } ,

                                    {
                                        label: 'Efficiency',
                                        fillColor: "green",
                                        strokeColor: "green",
                                        data: chartData1

                                    } ]
        };

                    var skillsChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barData);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The change in the Controller:

```
 public ActionResult BartestChart()
        {
            List<string> returnData = getChartData();
            ViewBag.ChartOne = returnData;
            List<string> returnData1 = getChartData2();
            ViewBag.ChartTwo = returnData1;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: even if i wrote 2 labels the same result